# Can I use multiple "and" in a sentence?

Tags: grammar

I want to express myself in the following sentence, but I am not sure if this is  grammatically correct:

> After lots of trials and errors and overcoming setbacks and moments of frustration, xxx

My concern is that I seem to be using a lot of *and*s.

Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: After lots of trials and errors, overcoming setbacks and moments of frustration, ...

Comment: This is strictly a matter of style. Connecting each of your objects (*trials*, *errors*, *setbacks*, *frustrations*) with *and* instead of using commas emphasizes the difficulty of the task.

Comment: The use of multiple conjunctions (generally *and*) is called ***polysyndeton,*** and it's a particular rhetorical device, as @deadrat indicates. One of [these](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=polysyndeton+is%3Aa) is likely to be relevant.

Comment: Author Piers Anthony deliberately uses multiple ands. As @deadrat said, it's a matter of style.